# matching any part of a expression using grep

Tags: grep, regular-expressions

How Can I use grep so as to return me all matches for not only entire expression but also any part of the expression.

example:

grep "foobar" foo

where foo contains text foo
should give me a match

Comment: Why not just grep for "foo" in the first place then?

Comment: I want to check if a password contains any dictionary words. Thats why

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense, any part of 'foobar', includes f, fo, foo, foob, fooba, foobar, o, oo, oob, ooba, oobar, ob, oba, obar, b, ba, bar, a, ar.  If you have a dictionary full of words and you're grepping with it, it's already working as required (fish will match fishing), if your dictionary doesn't contain all word variants (only has fishing and not fish) that's a different issue

Comment: @Alek Sood: you store your passwords in plaintext????!!!!!

Comment: @symncbean haha...No dude! whats stored in plain text is a list of passwords not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simply grep on "foo". Without any flag, grep matches everything ; while the flag "-w or --word-regexp" does an exact matching.

Comment: I am using it to find if a password contains dictionary words.